# How do I recover .jpg files on Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, photorec

How do I recover delete files with just with just the .jpg extension in Ubuntu?

I already tried "photorec", but it recovered all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Photorec. It is the absolute best tool for this job.

When asked what partition to search, select the `[File Opt]` link at the bottom of the screen.

In there, tell it to only recover `jpg` files.

Let it run, and problem solved!

---

Alternatively, if you have already recovered, do this.

First off, you need to be in the `recup_dir` folder. Once you are in a terminal in this folder, run these commands:

```
mkdir ../Recovery/
sudo mv *.jpg ../Recovery
cd ..
sudo rm -rf recup_dir
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER Recovery/
```

Done! Note, the `recup_dir` folder will be deleted.

Comment: thank you so much. i think ill stay with ubuntu for a long while..

Comment: @kingandie If this answer solved your problem, please hit the check mark. Thanks!!

Comment: pardon my mistake..im really been looking for the line "hit thanks" or something like that..im new to this..now i know its a check..thnaks

Answer (score 0):

The "photorec" available on Ubuntu 14.04 recovers all files, not just jpgs. Install "foremost" instead and run this: `sudo foremost -t jpg -i /dev/sdb1`, where `/dev/sdb1` is changed to match the location of your Windows partition. That will recover just the JPEG format files.

This works regardless of the extension giving the file. That is, it will work on files named `.jpg`, `.JPG`, `.jpeg` and `.JPEG`.